# What type of architecture would I need to deal with partially-completed operations in the event of a server crash?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, architecture

I have been working on a social network powered by ASP.NET 5 for just over six months.

As I think about my architecture, I realize that there are a variety of issues with it. One of the biggest issues is that, in the event that the server would go down (for whatever reason), any operation that was occurring at the time of the outage would be lost. For example, a user deleting a picture album, and the pictures associated with it. The system deletes the album record and then the server crashes. Upon reboot, the delete operation would be lost, and my database would then be cluttered with redundant picture records and my storage server would have redundant image files.

What sort of architecture would allow me to solve this issue?

Comment: Given this is a "whiteboard" question and not a "coding" question, while interesting, I'm flagging to move to programmers.SE.

Comment: One thing you could potentially do to ensure easy atomicity is just mark a photo album as removed. The album and all photos associated no longer show up to the user when an album is marked this way. That should be pretty easy to do as an atomic transaction and takes care of the immediate user-end side. The next step is cleanup, and that may be more difficult to bundle up as an atomic transaction (but it doesn't have to be once we take care of the user-end side). There, even on server failure, you could resume the cleanup process on restart by looking for albums marked for removal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really expect this to become a problem, you may want to spend some more money on servers that stay up.

That being said, this edge case is always present. There can always be an HTTP request that is still in-flight between the client and the server, or that has *just* arrived at the first line of your code while the server goes down - without you having stored the request data, so you cannot repeat it.

There's really nothing you can do about that principle.

You can use transactions to let database operations remain [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)) (i.e. all of it happens or none of it does), but when you've got work that needs to happen in both database and filesystem to stay synchronized, you've got a different problem.

You can however introduce some kind of job system. A "delete photo album job" could look like this:

1. User clicks "Delete album".
2. System stores a "DeleteAlbumJob" in the database. The album stays online (database) and present (filesystem).
3. Job system processes jobs until marked as successfully completed.

The job system, [for example one through Hangfire](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx), processes these jobs step by step - recording where it is. Now for example, the photos from the album have been removed from the filesystem, but the album still exists in the database, and the server goes down. Now the next reboot, the service will start again and the job wil continue to be processed from where it was left.

In the same transaction as creating the job in a database, you can flag the album as "DeletionPending", so it won't be shown to the user anymore.